# How to lock a certain page in flutter?

Tags: flutter, screen-lock

Im currently building pomodoro app with flutter.
I want to add functionality that it locks up the phone during the locked time.
What I mean  is that I cannot unlock and go back even if I restart my phone again. The locked screen should pop up immediately if I restart the phone.
Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Ive tried some lock-screen library in pub.dev but I could not find the exact library that meets my requirement.

Comment: create a main page that has a Datetime listener. Have an else-if statement where when the time of Datetime.now() reaches specific times, return a locked screen, else return homepage

Comment: Thanks for the comment but Im not looking for something that just routes when a specific condition meets. I want to make a functionality that there is no other way to leave the locked screen while the app is on locked state.

Comment: oh ok well still the same idea, a main page that has a datetime listener with an else-if statement that returns home page. and the else-if statement instead of returning the page, it will change a bool, so that bool should be a global bool. Then on every page you allow Navigation conditionally

Comment: The method you have just mentioned would definately lock the app internally. Ive also found similar flutter library that could lock the app internally. https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_lock
However, I want to make the app locked externally too. For instanse, the user cannot use any other apps while the app is in the locked state. And this locked state should not be unlocked by just restarting the phone also.

Comment: I dont think its possible to prevent users from using other apps due to apple-store & google-play restrictions that protect users. So even if u managed to implement a function, they probably wont approve ur app in their store unless you crack/jailbreak the device which is not recommended. If u check [apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#app-behavior) section 2.5, they explain that attempting to block or interfere with other apps or system will be rejected, including apps that run continuously in the background for too long and changes functionalities